# Create a new anonymous type list to union onto existing anonymous type list

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a list of anonymous types that I get from my database:

```
var takenChannels = (from b in bq.GetStuff(db)
                     where b.RecordType == "H" && b.TourStartDateTime.Date == date
                     select new { Start = b.TourStartDateTime, End = b.TourEndDateTime, Channel = b.RadioChannel, TourArea = b.TourArea }).ToList();
```

Then I use this list info to do some stuff in a foreach loop. I want to add to this list a new anonymous item for when I come back round in the loop.

Something like:

```
takenChannels.Union{new[] { new{Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Channel = 25, TourArea = "Area" }});
```

Obviously this doesn't work. How do I do it?

**Edit 1:**

```
takenChannels.Add(new { Start = s, End = e, Channel = channel, TourArea = booking.TourArea });
```

This is the closest I've got so far (Thanks to Daniel)... but the error I get is:

> Error  6   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#2' to 'AnonymousType#1'

Comment: `Obviously this doesn't work.`  No, it's not obvious.  Does that generate an error?  If so, what?  I wouldn't suspect it to not work.  Note that `Union` doesn't mutate the list, it creates a new sequence, so you'll need to assign that to something to observe the result.

Comment: Sorry, I've been messing with my code. There's a mash of 2 attempted solutions there. I've edited my Q.

Comment: The types of the properties must not match up properly.  Perhaps one of them is a string in one place and an int in another, or something like that.  If you ensure that you have the same properties with *exactly* the same names and *exactly* the same types then it'll work just fine.

Comment: Spot on, RadioChannel and EndDateTime are nullable values. Many thanks @Servy :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This answer might be a bit late, but since this is the question I found when Googling for the same problem, I think I should complete it with a working answer.

There is no problem to `Union` multiple times over anonymous types. It is important that all properties are declared in all instances and that they have **the same data type**. if not, you get the error above.

- In your specific case, does the database perhaps return `TourStartDateTime` or `TourEndDateTime` as `DateTime?`?
- Is `RadioChannel` an `int` from the database or perhaps an `int?` or `string`?
- Is `TourArea` a `string` in the database?

Just make sure the data types match and you should be fine. Below is a working snippet of code I use in my own program:

```
var regions = (
    new[] { new { Id = "-1", Name = "---", Pattern = (string)null } }
  ).Union(
    from x in db.Userlists where x.ListType == 2 select new { Id = x.UserlistID.ToString(), Name = x.Name, Pattern = (string)null }
  ).Union(
    from x in db.Lookups where x.Category == "Stock" select new { Id = x.Key, Name = x.Key, Pattern = x.Value }
  ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply `Add` to the list:

```
takenChannels.Add(new { Start = ... });
```

Comment: May I add... being sure the names and types of the anonymous type object you add are the same as the list items.