# Anonymous Type Error using Union

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use `Union` and my variable type is decimal. I am getting the following exception:

> Instance argument:cannot convert from '`System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>`' to '`System.Linq.ParalelQuery<AnonymousType#2>`'

And the code:

```
queryResults = (from lI in Entities.LI
               select new { lI, lI.abc })
               .Union(from lI in Entities.LI
                             from R in Entities.RL
                             where lI.oid == R.lIOid 
                             select new { lI, R.Quantity });
```

Comment: the answer you choose (from the below 2 answers) would depend on what the type of abc is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Union` two anonymous types as long as their types are the same. This includes field names. In your case, the first type is `{lI, abc}` and the second one is `{lI, Quantity}`, so merging them wouldn't work. You need to decide on a single name, - `Quantity`, `abc`, or something completely different.

Giving both fields identical names will fix the problem, assuming that their types are already the same:

```
queryResults = (from lI in Entities.LI
           select new { lI, Quantity = lI.abc }) // <<== Added "Quantity ="
           .Union(from lI in Entities.LI
                         from R in Entities.RL
                         where lI.oid == R.lIOid 
                         select new { lI, R.Quantity });
```

Answer (score 5):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. You can't convert one anonymous type to another.

You have this as your first select statement:

```
select new { lI, lI.abc }
```

and this as your second:

```
select new { lI, R.Quantity }
```

These are producing two different objects, the first has whatever `lI` is plus a string. The second has 'lI` and a numeric value.

Try this:

```
select new { lI, lI.abc, 0 }
```

and:

```
select new { lI, "", R.Quantity }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it work if the datatypes were the same? As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947761/create-a-new-anonymous-type-list-to-union-onto-existing-anonymous-type-list?

Comment: @stuartd, yes it should. I was just adding a possible solution.