# Oracle query to LINQ

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, linq

We are moving our data layer from oracle to entity framework.
Am trying to write this oracle query in LINQ

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT   ld203_entity_id, ld203_entity_nm
              FROM f.ld203_ent_lst
             WHERE ld203_ent_nm <> 'Other' and LD203_ENT_HIDE='Y'
          ORDER BY ld203_ent_nm ASC)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT   ld203_ent_id, ld203_ent_nm
              FROM f.ld203_ent_list 
             WHERE ld203_ent_nm = 'Other' and LD203_ENT_HIDE='Y'
          ORDER BY ld203_ent_nm ASC);
```

LINQ query am trying ..

```
var ls =
                (from a in context.ld203_entity_list
                 where (a.ld203_entity_nm != "Other" && a.ld203_entity_hide == "Y")
                 select a.ld203_entity_id, a.ld203_entity_nm)
                .Union
                    (from b in context.ld203_entity_list
                     where b.ld203_entity_nm == "Other" && b.ld203_entity_hide == "Y"
                     select b.ld203_entity_id, b.ld203_entity_nm);

                dt = LINQResultToDataTable(ls);
```

Can any one help with which way to rewrite this in LINQ C#.?

Comment: What have you tried so far in LINQ? Show us your entity model and code.

Comment: added the linq code am trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anonymous type in order to use `Union` as follow:

```
var ls = (from a in context.ld203_entity_list
          where (a.ld203_entity_nm != "Other" && a.ld203_entity_hide == "Y")
          select new { Id = a.ld203_entity_id, Num = a.ld203_entity_nm } )
         .Union
            (from b in context.ld203_entity_list
             where b.ld203_entity_nm == "Other" && b.ld203_entity_hide == "Y"
             select new { Id = b.ld203_ent_id, Num = b.ld203_ent_nm});
```

Note that all properties are declared in all instances and they must have the same data type. (For example, in your case data type of these `ld203_entity_id` and `ld203_ent_id` must be the same)

For more info have a look at: [Create a new anonymous type list to union onto existing anonymous type list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947761/create-a-new-anonymous-type-list-to-union-onto-existing-anonymous-type-list)

Comment: Thank you Selim.